# Fetching value from tag without using id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="typeahead-result">
    <ul class="typeahead-list">
      <li>
        <a data-index="0" data-group="Restaurant" href="javascript:;"><strong>Cafe</strong> Hollywood <small style="color:#999;">Restaurant</small></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-index="1" data-group="Estb" href="javascript:;"><strong>cafe</strong><small style="color:#999;">Estb</small></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here I am having the text value of `<a>` tag that is **"Cafe Hollywood"** and I want its attribute value for `data-group="?"`

Comment: So on click of anchor tag you want associated `small` tag?

Comment: You want a value of the second small tag? Use $("small:eq(1))

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('[data-group="Estb"] small').text();
```

Comment: actually i can use only the div class "typeahead-result" inside this all the attributes are dynamic but the tags are not

Comment: friend here i am having the text vale of tag that is "Cafe Hollywood" and i want its attribute value for data-group="?"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<small>`, you could use `<span id="spanId" style="font-size:small">`

Then you would be able to call the span in your javascript. Yes, your version is a bit shorter, but in the long run you want to avoid deprecated tags like `<small>, <underline>, <b>`, etc exactly because of problems like this

Comment: I've noticed that, but then I saw his code and assumed there is no actual reason not to use a class or id

Comment: this are dynamically generated by typeahead.js

Comment: Now I see. Sorry for my answer. You might want to put that in the description though

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alert($("li").eq(1).find("a").attr("data-group"));
```

Comment: ok can i know the what the value inside the data-group who have text cafe

Comment: no friend i want the attribute vale "cafe" not its text

Comment: i want the attribute value

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can directly get the value of each `small` tag, as follows:

```
var my_small_value;
$('li').getChildren().find('small').click(function(){

        my_small_value = this.text();
        alert(my_small_value);
});
```